# Can I use my Mac's Bluetooth as a Personal Network?

Tags: windows, imac, bluetooth, tethering

I'm writing this question on my iMac. It's connected to the internet via WiFi as my modem/router is in another room. My iMac has bluetooth running for my magic mouse and apple keyboard.

I've also got a PC here at home, running Windows 8 (I'm an MSDN subscriber) and it has a Bluetooth adapter and an ethernet port.

Currently, I can't connect the ethernet adapter because we're waiting for the wiring to be connected up.

Can the Windows PC share the Mac's WiFi internet connection via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System Preferences > Sharing, click "Internet Sharing" on the left. In the "Share your connection from" menu, choose "Wi-Fi," and then in the "To computers using" list, choose "Bluetooth PAN." Then check the box next to "Internet Sharing" in the list on the left to enable it.

[image: sharing]

(The options in the screenshot are only greyed out because you can't change them once Internet Sharing is on).

Comment: Thanks heaps :) Prompt answer and was exactly what I needed. Cheers!